# Why is this else statement not returning False?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm doing python bats and the question '*has23*' says the following:

Given an int array length 2, return **True** if it contains a 2 or a 3.

I have written this code so far expecting it to work as intended with the else statement but I cannot trigger the False if 2 or 3 is not found within the array.

```
def has23(nums):
  if 2 or 3 in nums:
    return True

  else:
    return False
```

Comment: `return any(x in nums for x in [2,3])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to completely write conditions that are separated by `and` or `or`. You code was actually checking `if 2` or `if 3 in nums`. `if 2` actually checks if 2 is nonzero, which is always true.

```py
def has23(nums):
  if 2 in nums or 3 in nums:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it was probably something small but I thought my logic was correct. This made sense and helped me out.

Comment: good answer and correct but effectively doubles the complexity

this has an unnesscessary loop `set([2,3]).intersection(nums)` would probably be more efficient(but honestly unlikely to make much of a difference(depending on size of nums))

Answer (score 0):

Writing `2 or 3 in nums` actually means, in Python, `(2) or (3 in nums)`. Which will *always* evaluate to `True` because `2` is a truthy value. What you should write instead to perform your intent here is `2 in nums or 3 in nums`.